# Show confirm dialog when click the save button

Tags: react-admin

I am now working on the project with react-admin, I want to show a confirm dialog instead of optimistic rendering when user clicks the save button.  I set the undoable = false, but it's not working.

`<Edit undoable={false} {...props}> </Edit>`

Answer (score 1):

Some hack with confirm dialog but it works. Use

> handleSubmitWithRedirect

```
<Toolbar {...props}>
    <SaveButton
      label=“Approve”
      redirect=“edit”
      submitOnEnter={false}
      icon={<></>}
      invalid={false}
      handleSubmitWithRedirect={
        () => {
          if(!window.confirm(‘Are you sure?’))
            return false;
          return props.handleSubmitWithRedirect();
        }
      }
    />
  </Toolbar>
```